# Como interceptar o evento de save do projeto no vssdk?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk, extension

Atualmente estou desenvolvendo uma extensão do visual studio 2017 onde preciso saber quando alguma alteração no projeto for persistida.

Ex.: Quando eu adiciono uma nova referência no projeto (sei que existe eventos para quando a referência for adicionada/alterada/removida, mas não atendeu minha necessidade), o projeto é marcado como pendente de ser salvo. Eu preciso interceptar quando ele for salvo (melhor se for antes de salvar)

Tentei os evento `Dte.Events.DocumentEvents.DocumentSaved`, mas não é disparado no salvar do projeto; `DTE.Events.SolutionEvents` e `DTE.Events.SolutionItemEvents` não possuem nenhum evento do tipo que preciso

Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que funcionou pra mim como uma luva foi implementar a interface `IVsRunningDocTableEvents3` fazendo override no método `OnBeforeSave`.

Dessa forma eu sabia exatamente quando o projeto estava para ser salvo e realizar as ações que precisava.

Ex.:

```
uint cookie;
var runningDocumentTable = (IVsRunningDocumentTable)GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsRunningDocumentTable));

runningDocumentTable.AdviseRunningDocTableEvents(new RunningDocTableEventsHandler(), out cookie);
```

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

namespace YourProject
{
    internal class RunningDocTableEventsHandler : IVsRunningDocTableEvents3
    {

        #region Methods

        public int OnAfterFirstDocumentLock(uint docCookie, uint dwRDTLockType, uint dwReadLocksRemaining, uint dwEditLocksRemaining)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnBeforeLastDocumentUnlock(uint docCookie, uint dwRDTLockType, uint dwReadLocksRemaining, uint dwEditLocksRemaining)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterSave(uint docCookie)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterAttributeChange(uint docCookie, uint grfAttribs)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(uint docCookie, int fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterDocumentWindowHide(uint docCookie, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterAttributeChangeEx(uint docCookie, uint grfAttribs, IVsHierarchy pHierOld, uint itemidOld, string pszMkDocumentOld, IVsHierarchy pHierNew, uint itemidNew, string pszMkDocumentNew)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnBeforeSave(uint docCookie)
        {
            /////// MY CODE ////////
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com este [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0857a868-e650-42ed-b9cc-2975dc46e994/addin-documentevents-are-not-triggered?forum=vsx) da MSDN, você precisar criar referências dos objetos `Events` e `DocumentEvents`, senão eles serão coletados pelo `Garbage Collector`e serão inutilizados.

**Exemplo:**

```
private EnvDTE.Events events;
private EnvDTE.DocumentEvents documentEvents;

MeuConstrutor()
{
    events = DTE.Events;
    documentEvents = events.DocumentEvents;
    documentEvents.DocumentSaved += OnDocumentSaved; // <- Adicione seu event handler aqui.
}
```